# Where does Bingplaces information appear?

Tags: bing

I've updated bingplaces.com with description, images, hours of operation, secondary phone, fax, email and website.

All I see though in Bing Maps is still the address and one phone number.

Where does all of the additional information they asked for even show up?

**Edit:**

I've now found some of this content on Bing if I type in EXACTLY the company name. It will show on the right side with company name, map, address, phone, website, and hours.

I still have no idea where, if anywhere, the logo and photos are being used though?

Comment: Maybe you need to be patient because a validation is pending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After about 2 weeks of checking every day I slowed down checking but at some point they finally did show up.

If I type in the exact name the images all show up. Additionally, I can now click on the map and it directs me to a `bing.com/local/?lid....` which has all of our information, images, and contact stuff on the left then map on the right.

So if anyone else is having this issue I'd say give it a good 6 to 8 weeks for the images.